# Data from function is null on first load

Tags: reactjs, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, expo

I'm using a function from another file to get data from a Firebase. However, the first time I load the app, I don't get the data. Data pulls it out fine. When I write to the console right after adding it to a variable, I see them. However, Return does not return them and returns only an empty field.

If I edit and save the file after loading, the application is refreshed and the data is loaded. Is this solution correct? Then I want to have more functions there.

```
const Page = () => {
  const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);

  const fetchMainCategories = async () => {
    const results = placesB.getMainCategories();
    setCategories(results);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchMainCategories();
  }, []);

}
export default Page;
```

```
class Categories {
    getMainCategories(){
        let val = [];
        const reference = query(ref(db, 'categories/1/'));
        onValue(reference, (snapshot) => {
            val = snapshot.val();
            console.log(val); // It always lists the data here
        });
        return val; // HERE IS THE PROBLEM. On the first load is this empty!
    }
}
const cats = new Categories();
export default cats;
```

Is here anyone who can help me please?

Comment: Are you trying get data only once for want to listen for realtime updates?

Comment: can you try returning promise from getmainCategories function, resolve when you get the data and await in `const results = await placesB.getMainCategories()`

Comment: @Dharmaraj I need it once.

Comment: @tarzenchugh Unfortunately, that won't help me. It either returns data or an empty field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `onValue()` returns data asynchronously and hence the array is always returned empty. Since you need to fetch data only once, use `get()` instead of   `onValue()`:

```
class Categories {
    // async 
    async getMainCategories() {
        const reference = query(ref(db, 'categories/1/'));
        const snap = await get(reference);
        return snap.val();
    }
}
```

Then you call this method as shown below:

```
const fetchMainCategories = async () => {
  // await here
  const results = await placesB.getMainCategories();
  console.log(results);
  setCategories(results);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put a condition, as if(val) then return val....

Comment: That won't help. During the first loading, the variable is empty even though it reads the data.

Comment: Suggestions are not answers

Comment: Duely noticed Dan!